# .htaccess Require Password On Each Visit?

Tags: .htaccess, passwords, password-protection, .htpasswd

What would the string of code be to throw within my .htaccess file that would force a re-enter of password and username on visit?

I only ask this because I have noticed that once the cache is cleared, it asks for the password again. I want it to ask everytime.

Ideas?

Thank you!
Aaron

Comment: like this: http://bignosebird.com/apache/a10.shtml?